# Spark saveAsTable append saves data to hive but throws an error: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.alterTable

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, hive

I'm trying to append data into an existing table in hive. but when I call

```
sdf.write.format("parquet").mode("append").saveAsTable("db.tbl", path=hdfs_path)
```

Data is saved successfully, but I get this error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o152.saveAsTable.
: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.alterTable(java.lang.String, org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Table, org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.EnvironmentContext)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1786)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.Shim.findMethod(HiveShim.scala:177)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.Shim_v2_1.alterTableMethod$lzycompute(HiveShim.scala:1183)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.Shim_v2_1.alterTableMethod(HiveShim.scala:1177)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.Shim_v2_1.alterTable(HiveShim.scala:1230)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.$anonfun$alterTable$1(HiveClientImpl.scala:572)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.$anonfun$withHiveState$1(HiveClientImpl.scala:294)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.liftedTree1$1(HiveClientImpl.scala:227)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.retryLocked(HiveClientImpl.scala:226)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.withHiveState(HiveClientImpl.scala:276)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.alterTable(HiveClientImpl.scala:562)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClient.alterTable(HiveClient.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClient.alterTable$(HiveClient.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.alterTable(HiveClientImpl.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.$anonfun$alterTableStats$1(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:719)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.alterTableStats(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:705)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.ExternalCatalogWithListener.alterTableStats(ExternalCatalogWithListener.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.alterTableStats(SessionCatalog.scala:420)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.CommandUtils$.updateTableStats(CommandUtils.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.writeAndRead(DataSource.scala:538)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.CreateDataSourceTableAsSelectCommand.saveDataIntoTable(createDataSourceTables.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.CreateDataSourceTableAsSelectCommand.run(createDataSourceTables.scala:167)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:175)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:171)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.$anonfun$runCommand$1(DataFrameWriter.scala:963)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:764)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:963)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.createTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:727)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:705)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:603)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I tried some alternatives too:

```
sdf.write.insertInto("db.tbl",overwrite=False)
sdf.write.mode("append").insertInto("db.tbl")
spark.sql("insert into table value(...)")
```

But with the same issue. It looks like any attempt to add data to an existing table succeed with throwing that error.

The "overwrite" mode is working good.

The spark version I'm using is 3.0.1
The hive version I'm using is 3.1.0

Have anyone faced this issue before?

Answer (score 1):

This look like some hive metastore artifacts referred in spark 3 is hive 2.x and not 3.x which you were using.

Comment: When I printed the spark configuration, I got this ('spark.sql.hive.metastore.version', '3.0'). As the spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars = standalone-metastore-1.21.2.3.1.4.41-5-hive3.jar

Comment: Also in the spark2-client/jars folder I found this used jar: hive-metastore-1.21.2.3.1.4.41-5.jar

Answer (score 1):

You're definitely having wrong Hive jar in your environment:

- Your spark is referring to [Hive 3.x](https://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r3.1.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/metadata/Hive.html#alterTable-java.lang.String-org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Table-org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.EnvironmentContext-), which has this method `alterTable(String, Table, EnvironmentContext)`
- However according to your comment, you have `hive-metastore-1.21.2.3.1.4.41-5.jar`, which is under Hortonwork distribution and you can [download the source code](https://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases/org/spark-project/hive/hive-packaging/1.21.2.3.1.4.41-5/) and verify yourself, that there is no such method.